# Vuetify v-tabs leave left area blank

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify in Vuejs / Nuxt project.

The v-tabs control is really nice but when having a very small screen it leaves unnecessary white space in the left:

[image]

Although telling show-arrows=false:

```
    <v-col cols="12" md="8" lg="9">
      <v-tabs
        coninuous
        :show-arrows="false"
        color="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)"
        centered
        center-active
        icons-and-text
      >
```

Does anybody has an idea how to take the full width of the visible screen for the v-tabs component?

Comment: Try using `grow` props for `v-tabs`

Comment: Very good idea... but also don't fill the space on the left which comes up when few width is available (and items aren't able to fully shown within the visible area. But instead of using complete left to right width it always leave the blank div. You can see e.g. here in better details: https://i.imgur.com/otLSQKv.png

Comment: Maybe it's because of `show-arrows` prop. Remove this completely and see what happen.

Comment: There is an open issue regarding this problem on [vuetify's github](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/12274).

Answer (score 1):

There are such cases in vuetify but as a same problem I solved it by adding my custom css to `.v-tab`

```css
.v-tab {
    letter-spacing: normal !important;
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: row !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
    margin: 13px 13px;
}
```